# How does the kernel sends I/O requests to a hard drive?

Tags: kernel, hard-disk, hardware, io

Supposedly I have a file that's distributed among different sectors. As an example, assuming both physical and logical sectors are 512B. A user process issues a request for the kernel to read the file. Let's say this file uses 3 distributed sectors on the hard drive.

1) Does the hard drive read all of the sectors at once and send the whole (512 * 3) data to the kernel?

*The 3 sectors are read in full by the hard drive first and then the data gets transferred to the kernel, 512 * 3 bytes gets transferred from HDD to kernel.

2) Do HDDs read multiple sectors at once? This seems more of a hardware related question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. Modern kernels of Unix-like operating systems tend to have pretty complex code to make I/O faster. The best known feature is caching: if a sector has been read in the past, there may still be a copy in memory, in which case no request is sent to the hard drive at all. Other typical acceleration features include out-of-order access (when there are many pending requests, the kernel may issue them in a different order to minimize seeks or to better exploit parallelism allowed by the hardware), and prefetching (the kernel assumes that if sectors 0 through 5 of a file have been read then it's likely that sector 6 will be read, to it will read sector 6 into the cache if it has nothing better to do).

Whether it's possible to issue the request to read sector 1 before the request to read sector 0 has been completed depends on the capabilities of the disk bus and of the disk. There's no general answer.

Comment: How does kernel receive data from the disk drive? For example, the HDD combines the sectors and send them together or send one sector at a time? I'm not sure even if HDDs are capable of reading multiple sectors at once and combine them and send them to the kernel.

Comment: @direprobs some (many perhaps nowadays) are, look up “scatter-gather”.

Comment: Data reads and writes are initiated by sending sending commands over the SATA or SCSI (or whatever interface is used). The commands include the logical block address (LBA) of the first sector to be read, and the number of consecutive sectors to be transferred. Typically Direct Memory Access (DMA) is used: the host controller is programmed with the memory address where to/from the data is read, without involving the CPU at all. When the transfer is complete, an interrupt is sent to the CPU to inform it that the transfer is complete.

Comment: @StephenKitt scatter-gather is related to the kernel.  However, I'm asking specifically about the methodology that the kernel uses to take data from the hard drive, either in multiple sectors at once or one sector at a time.

Comment: @direprobs scatter-gather is implemented by chipsets and/or drives, it’s not (just) related to the kernel.

Comment: Modern drives and host controllers also support command queues, which means there can be several commands "in flight" on the drive, and the drive can reorder them to optimise disk access.

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't know if I got you right. That means, the hard drive reads multiple sectors and puts the read sectors in a buffer, after that the hard drive gives the data to the kernel.

Comment: @direprobs It depends on the bus type, on the host controller and on the drive chipset and firmware (and on the driver's ability to fully exploit all the possibilities). That's why I'm not being more precise.

Comment: @Gilles I see your point now.

Comment: @StephenKitt I think it is a bit misleading to talk about scatter-gather in the context of this question, at least when it comes to SATA disks. First of all, reading several sectors in a single command does not need scatter-gather, if the consecutive sectors are placed in consecutive memory locations on the host. Second, scatter-gather applies only to the host controller and the CPU; the SATA protocol does not mention scatter-gather at all. Modern host controllers support scatter-gather, but a single scatter list is only used for a single (queued) SATA command.

Comment: @Johan I guess it depends on whether the OP is interested in what hard drives support (on their own), or on what happens at the interface between the kernel and the storage hardware (since the kernel interacts with controllers, not storage directly, at least on SCSI, SAS and SATA), and what the interrupt granularity is (and then let’s throw in DMA controllers to add to the fun). The question is too broad really.